Google Apps Script Redirects After Login to filtered google sheet
Create a login section with Google Apps Script and after the user logs in, you can view google sheet information filtered by that user. Unable to create a pass-through section and a filter section beyond the login section. Please help me with this.
All this part will be visible on one page of google sites

You need to create web application based on google apps script. After user login  success, take the user id or (email) to filter spreadsheet data in the back end. The show the result data (table) to the front end part. This takes a bit of more effort to develop the UI but it is certainly fruitful.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
